# Global variable is not recognized

Tags: c++, global-variables, global

I have written a function that receives a float array x and does some
 operations with it. The dimension of this array is given by the number
 of lines in a file. To automate this process I have written a
 function that reads the file and returns the number of lines.

```
 int dim(){
 unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
 FILE *file = fopen("prod.txt", "r");
 int ch;

 while (EOF != (ch=getc(file)))
     if ('\n' == ch)
         ++number_of_lines;

 return number_of_lines;
 }
```

Then, I declare this value as a global variable:

```
 const int numofdims = dim();
```

However when I call the function `cost` in `main` (after initializing the array `x[numofdims]`)

```
 float cost(x[numofdims]){
     int i,j;
     float v = 0;
     vector<float x_in;
     vector<float x_origin;
     for(i=0;i<numofdims;i++){
         x_origin.push_back(x[i]);
         x_in.push_back(x[i]);
    // does several calculations
    // ...
      return v;
 }

 int main(){

  float x[46] = {1.92215242,   6.27128854,   9.53873027,  14.79595426,
     18.92807696,  25.85703415,  29.93216819,  33.84737516,
     42.19055   ,  48.81144008,  60.99963933,  63.34494338,
     67.69622093,  73.07859412,  80.46676915,  85.10451921,
     87.49178446,  92.34202212,  96.37983996,  98.90903662,
    101.99359444, 106.88409251, 113.81421998, 120.42050161,
    124.43256197, 126.96629951, 133.88193576, 139.48952166,
    149.57054363, 155.55769723, 159.66096967, 167.09857013,
    173.4584723 , 176.70360324, 181.43200013, 182.80392359,
    185.65336252, 187.64028963, 191.06631673, 193.69478216,
    198.94720133, 202.68384665, 209.7697676 , 212.26092809,
    219.06840905, 221.61314655};
 printf("%d", numofdims);
 float v = cost(x);
 }
```

I get the errors

```
 array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
 float cost(float x[numofdims]){

 array_param.cpp: In function ‘float cost(...)’:
 array_param.cpp:232:28: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
      x_origin.push_back(x[i]);
```

However, if, instead of attributing dim() to the variable numofdims, I do

```
 const int numofdims = 46;
```

where 46 is the number of lines of one of the files I want to read,
 the function works exactly how I expected. In both cases of
 declaration of numfodims (with dim() or the numerical attribution),
 when I print

```
 printf("%d", numofdims);
```

I obtain the value 46. Why is this happening, and how can I prevent
 it?

Comment: The value of your constant has to be known at compile time to be used in an array declaration.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thank you! However, I really wish I could do something like I described since I don't want to change the value of the constant every time I have a new file. Is there something possible to do in this case?

Comment: Use a std::vector instead of a fixed size array. Also avoid using globals at all.